# Is there a way for python to detect the system audio output? Say from the output of Quicktime player / VLC?

Tags: python, audio

If yes, can python detect the number of audio channels from the sytem audio output stream and write that audio to a .wav file? I am looking for a method for all three platforms - mac, win and linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would first look at the PyAudio library-> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAudio/

Comment: Yeah I tried that already. It provides a way to read from the input stream or write to the output stream.

I kind of need a way to read from the system audio output stream. I hope thats possible.